# Flutter when text is bigger than input, text disappears

Tags: flutter

The problem is that when the text is bigger than the input size, the  text just disappears and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
TextField(
    focusNode: _focusEmailNode,
    controller: _emailController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: txtEmailBoder),
    ),
    hintText: 'Email',
),
```

[image]

Comment: Same here... Did you find something?

Comment: I don't if you have resolved this issue, but I had similar, and in may case I discovered that I needed more vertical space on the textfield, reducing the contentPadding in the input decoration resolved my issue.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. I kinda want to truncate the text with ellipses when editing is finished.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero
```

to your `InputDecoration`

Answer (score 5):

After searching through many sites, I finally got a solution. You can solve this problem by giving `decoration and maxlines` in the textfield. Give `isDense as true` in `InputDecoration`
Example:

```
Container(
  height: 20,
  width: 100,
  child: TextFormField(
    maxLines: 1,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      isDense: true,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0),
    ),
    onChanged: (value) {
      print(value);
    },
  ),
);
```

if you don't give content padding then your text will be cut from the middle, like below.
[image]

Be careful when you give padding, you should give padding as needed by your textfield's height. If you give wrong padding then also your text will be invisible.

Answer (score 4):

Give text field an input formatter with desired length of the text like this:

```
 inputFormatters: [
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(50),
      ],
```

And then have content padding set to like this :

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0 , 20.0 , 5.0 , 20.0),
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, and solved it by adding `decoration` property to `TextField` like this:

```dart
decoration: const InputDecoration(
  isCollapsed: true,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 50, 5.0, 10.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                ),
                hintText: 'Email',
              ),
            )));
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To Prevent this disappearing use decoration as 
`InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Search Customer")`

Full Code is
 `TextField(decoration : InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Search Customer"), textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences)`

Answer (score 0):

Bottom `contentPadding` set to a small (e.g. 5) value and `isDense: true` were key for my situation:

```
child: TextFormField(
  controller: pwc.tec,
  maxLength: 4,
  onTapOutside: (event) => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5), // ←←
    isDense: true, // ←←
    helperText: '',
  ),
)
```

`isDense: true` causes the TextField to use less vertical space.

Specifying some small values for the bottom `contentPadding` prevents TextField from using its default (i.e. large) values when input text is nearing max width.  The large (default) contentPadding values can cause the input text to 'pop' upwards making it invisible.

*Side note*: specifying `helperText` (even as emptystring) prevents the field from changing height when transitioning from empty to entering values.

Answer (score 0):

set height to 1 in TextStyle of TextField.

```
     TextField(
        style: TextStyle(height: 1),
      )
```